# Why I can't get return prime factors of a given number in a linked list?I added the structure,function,main and the print function

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

---

I am trying to find prime factors of a given number N and return them in  alinked list.There is not a problem with finding the prime factors but I have problem with returning them in  a linked list...I am not getting an error when I run the code but I only get first prime factor as an output,can not get the rest ,for example if N is equal to 72,I get 2 as an output but can't rest of the factors

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    //This is my structure
    typedef struct SinglyLinkedListItem
    {
        int data;
        struct SinglyLinkedListItem*next;
    }SLLI;

    //This is my function to find the prime factor and return in  a linked list
   SLLI*PrimeFactor(SLLI*prime,int N)
   {
    SLLI*pList=NULL;
    int i,j,isPrime;
    for (i = 2; i <= N; i++)
    {
        if(N % i == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 1;
            for (j = 2; j <= i/2; j++)
            {
                if(i % j == 0)
                {
                    isPrime = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            //Most probably problem is after this part of the code
            if(isPrime == 1)
            {
                //Adding first factor to the list
                if(pList==NULL)
                {
                    pList=malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
                    pList->data=i;
                    pList->next=NULL;
                    prime= pList;
                }

                //Trying to add rest of them but can't
                else
                {
                    pList->next = malloc(sizeof(SLLI));
                    pList->next->data = i;
                    pList->next->next = NULL;
                    pList = pList->next;
                }
            }
        }
   }
    return prime;
}

 void Printlist(SLLI*pHead)
 {
    SLLI*temp=pHead;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
  }

  int main()
  {
    SLLI*pHead=NULL;

    pHead=PrimeFactor(pHead,72);

    Printlist(pHead);


  }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour. I get 2 and 3 as prime factors for 72 = 2³·3². How do you print the prime factors? (By the way, `prime` should probably be a local variable, not an argument to the function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're just not printing them out correctly, it's hard to tell since you haven't included that code but, if you add a `main` thus:

```
int main(void) {
    SLLI * x = PrimeFactor(NULL, 72);
    while (x != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", x->data);
        x = x->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then you will get both `2` *and* `3`, which are the only prime factors of `72`: `72 = 2332 (8 x 9)`.

Similarly, `120` gives you `2`, `3`, and `5`: `120 = 233151 (8 x 3 x 5)`.

---

A couple of other points to consider:

- I'm not sure why you pass in `prime` to the function since you overwrite it anyway. You should remove that from the function definition and just have a local variable to hold the information.
- When checking for primality, you don't need to go to half the value, just to its square root. So a better loop would be: `for (j = 2; j * j <= i; j++)`.
- An even *better* check is to realise that, other than `2` and `3`, every prime is of the form `6n + 1` or `6n + 5`. That's because:

  - `6n + 0 = 6n`, a multiple of six;
  - `6n + 2 = 2(3n + 1)`, a multiple of two;
  - `6n + 3 = 3(2n + 1)`, a multiple of three;
  - `6n + 4 = 2(3n + 2)`, a multiple of two;

leaving only `6n + 1` and `6n + 5` as candidates (not every *one* of those is a prime (e.g., `6(4) + 1 = 25`) but the primes *can* be drawn exclusively from that set).

So an even better primality test is the following function:

```
// Function for checking primality.

int isPrime(int number) {
    // Special cases.

    if ((number == 2) || (number == 3)) return 1;
    if ((number % 2 == 0) || (number % 3 == 0)) return 0;
    if (number < 5) return 0;

    // Efficient selection of candidate primes, starting at 5, adding
    // 2 and 4 alternately: 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 25, 27, ...

    for (
        int candidate = 5, add = 2;
        candidate * candidate <= number;
        candidate += add, add = 6 - add
    ) {
        if (number % candidate == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

---

Using that function, and adding some extra functions to dump and free a list, and providing a test harness `main`, gives the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct sListItem
{
    int data;
    struct sListItem *next;
} ListItem;

// Function for checking primality.

int isPrime(int number) {
    // Special cases.

    if ((number == 2) || (number == 3)) return 1;
    if ((number % 2 == 0) || (number % 3 == 0)) return 0;
    if (number < 5) return 0;

    // Efficient selection of candidate primes, starting at 5, adding
    // 2 and 4 alternately: 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 25, 27, ...

    for (int candidate = 5, add = 2; candidate * candidate <= number; candidate += add, add = 6 - add)
        if (number % candidate == 0)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

// Function for returning list of prime factors.

ListItem *primeFactorList(int number) {
    ListItem *retVal = NULL;
    ListItem *lastItem;

    // Analyse possible factors, up to half of number.

    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2 + 1; divisor++) {
        if ((number % divisor == 0) && isPrime(divisor)) {
            if (retVal == NULL) {
                // Adding first item to list.

                retVal = lastItem = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
                lastItem->data = divisor;
                lastItem->next = NULL;
            } else {
                // Adding subsequent items to list.

                lastItem->next = malloc(sizeof(ListItem));
                lastItem = lastItem->next;
                lastItem->data = divisor;
                lastItem->next = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

// Dump a list.

void dumpList(int value, ListItem *head) {
    printf("%d:", value);
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf(" -> %d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

// Free a list.

void freeList(ListItem *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        ListItem *toDelete = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(toDelete);
    }
}

// Test program.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static int data[] = { 10, 24, 72, 120, 125, -1 };
    for (int *ptr = &(data[0]); *ptr >= 0; ptr++) {
        ListItem *list = primeFactorList(*ptr);
        dumpList(*ptr, list);
        freeList(list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And compiling and running that shows the results of the test harness (with my added comments on the right, and feel free to add any extra values to the `data` array if you want more testing):

```
10: -> 2 -> 5                   2 x 5
24: -> 2 -> 3                   2^3 x 3
72: -> 2 -> 3                   2^3 x 3^2
120: -> 2 -> 3 -> 5             2^3 x 3 x 5
125: -> 5                       5^3
```